# Extending a 2-d scatterplot heatmap to 3-d

Tags: r

Right now I make a 2-d heatmap using the below code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df=read.csv("C:/Users/sony/Desktop/Data.csv", header = TRUE)
qplot(df$knt, percent, data=df$percent, colour=df$avgTime,xlab=expression(paste('k'[s],"(N/m)")),ylab="Percentage of exiting agents") +
  scale_colour_continuous(name = "Average Time of exiting agents (sec)", low = "yellow", high = "black")
```

I wish to convert to 3-d plot the 3-dimension being a column named `df$k` and (name on graph) z label being, `k_e`. So can do so. I don't want to change the current display format ,that title for values.

I can't provide the actual data. But check the following:

**Data :**

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl, xlab = "MPG", ylab = "WT") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(name = "Cylinders", midpoint = median(mtcars$cyl),
                         low = "red", mid = "green", high = "black")
```

[image]

I wish to one shown below:
**3-d heatmap:(Interactive)**

[image]

Comment: Have you found any indication that ggplot2 functions are available for pseudo-3d plotting?

Comment: I think so it is possible using ggplot2, are you stating otherwise. In any case, I am not predisposed towards using ggplot2.

Comment: I'm not implying anything other than what I have read in the past: that ggplot2 doesn't do 3D. I could be out of date. If you have more recent information, you should provide it. If you want something else then you should say what version of 3D you want. There are three different plotting paradigms I can think of that provide such a facility. And ... please provide some data along with a better problem description.

Comment: @BondedDust Please check now it should make more sense. I found this link http://www.r-bloggers.com/3d-plots-with-ggplot2-and-plotly/ , but it is a bit confusing to me to extend my code using this.

Comment: In the `rgl` package, try `plot3d` : `with(mtcars,plot3d(wt, mpg, hp, col=cyl, size=3))`

Comment: @NicE How would specify the x,y,z and colour labels in the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an interactive 3D plot you can use:

```
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green","black"), space = "rgb")
library(rgl)
with(mtcars,plot3d(wt, mpg, hp, col=rgb.palette(30)[as.numeric(cut(mtcars$qsec,breaks=30))], size=3,xlab="x-axis",ylab="y-axis",zlab="z-axis",main="title"))
```

I'm not aware of the function to make the color legend.

If you want a static plot, you can use:

```
library(plot3D)
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green","black"), space = "rgb")
scatter3D(mtcars$wt,mtcars$mpg,mtcars$hp,colvar=mtcars$qsec,col=colorRampPalette(c("red", "green","black"))(200),pch=16,main="title",
          xlab="wt",ylab="mpg",zlab="hp",clab="Cyl",phi=20,theta=50,d=1,
          ticktype = "detailed",colkey = list(length = 0.5, width = 0.5, cex.clab = 0.75),
      bty = "g")
```

You can change the angle of the plot using `phi` and `theta` and remove the gridlines by removing `bty="g"`

Comment: Thanks! But if I specify the labels like xlab=expression(paste('k'[s],"(N/m)"))  they don't seem to work as opposed to before with qplot.

Comment: in first code of interactive 3-D plot how could one specify the color palette?

Comment: s is the subscript to k. It isnt a variable.

Comment: I wanted to display it like this (latex :) $k_s$, if that could be possible, it would be great.

Comment: If possible can you please specify by comments how one can change the color scale in both the diagrams. Something like :  (low = "red", mid = "green", high = "black")

Comment: yep edited it, unfortunately no subscript for scatter3D